# changing the style of a component which is being used by its selctor

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components

I am using a component with its selector in another component, like this:

```
<div class="col-xl-4" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <app-patient-info-accordion *ngIf="patient" [cardTitle]="'General Information'" [patient]="patient"></app-patient-info-accordion>
  </div>
```

now I want to set specific styles for elements inside of "app-patient-info-accordion" and I literally have no idea how to do it! any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

u can use `::ng-deep` on parent component to force style to `child component`

for example

**html**

```
<div class="main col-xl-4" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <app-patient-info-accordion *ngIf="patient" [cardTitle]="'General Information'" 
    [patient]="patient"></app-patient-info-accordion>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.main {
   ::ng-deep {
      .title  {
        color: red;
      }
   }
}
```

the `title class on child component` will get that color style.

read more on https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Comment: I haven't tried ::ng-deep since "app-patient-info-accordion" is not a child component! it's just a regular sibling component

Comment: this mean you have two sibling component and want to change style on element on component 1 by an action on component 2 ? 
you can emit value on  component1 and use ngClass on the other one for that style.